# jenkins start fails when runing 'systemctl start jenkins'

Tags: jenkins

run
`systemctl start jenkins`

show message

```
[root@localhost bin]# systemctl start jenkins
Job for jenkins.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status jenkins.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[root@localhost bin]# journalctl -xe
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
-- 
-- jenkins.service 单元已结束停止操作。
10月 11 10:14:04 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Jenkins Continuous Integration Server...
-- Subject: jenkins.service 单元已开始启动
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
-- 
-- jenkins.service 单元已开始启动。
10月 11 10:14:04 localhost.localdomain jenkins[29495]: Unrecognized VM option 'MaxpermSize=512m'
10月 11 10:14:04 localhost.localdomain jenkins[29495]: Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
10月 11 10:14:04 localhost.localdomain jenkins[29495]: Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
10月 11 10:14:04 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
10月 11 10:14:04 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
10月 11 10:14:04 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
-- Subject: jenkins.service 单元已失败
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
-- 
-- jenkins.service 单元已失败。
-- 
-- 结果为“RESULT”。
10月 11 10:14:05 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
10月 11 10:14:05 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
-- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
-- 
-- Automatic restarting of the unit jenkins.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
10月 11 10:14:05 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
-- Subject: jenkins.service 单元已结束停止操作
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
-- 
-- jenkins.service 单元已结束停止操作。
10月 11 10:14:05 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
10月 11 10:14:05 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
10月 11 10:14:05 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
-- Subject: jenkins.service 单元已失败
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
-- 
-- jenkins.service 单元已失败。
-- 
-- 结果为“RESULT”。
```

i installed java

```
[root@localhost bin]# java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_362"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_362-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.362-b08, mixed mode)
```

this is my java path

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_361-amd64
JRE_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_361-amd64/jre
```

the /etc/init.d/jendins

```
candidates="
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_361-amd64/bin/java
/etc/alternatives/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0/bin/java
/usr/bin/java
#/bin/java
"
```

what wrong?  help me